# Core Data Parent/Child context save fail

Tags: multithreading, core-data

I setup a background thread with the Parent/Child model. Essentially the context save is failing.

Here is my setup. In the AppDelegate i've setup the _managedObjectContext with the NSMainQueueConcurrencyType:

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    if (_managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return _managedObjectContext;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil) {

        _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];//[[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    }
    return _managedObjectContext;
}
```

In my data loading class I setup the parent/child mocs here to perform the work on the background thread:

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

dispatch_async(queue, ^{

    NSManagedObjectContext *mainMOC = self.managedObjectContext;
    NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSConfinementConcurrencyType];


    [moc setParentContext:mainMOC];
    [moc setUndoManager:nil];
```

When the json data has completed I attempt to peform a save operation with the following macro:

```
#define SAVE_MOC    { NSError *error; \
if (![moc save:&error]) { NSLog(@"Sub MOC Error"); } \
[mainMOC performBlock:^{  NSError *e = nil;  if (![mainMOC save:&e]) {    

NSLog(@"Main MOC Error %@",error.localizedDescription);}}];}
```

Also when i've completed the data load I jump back on the main thread like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    NSLog(@"<---- complete CS sub moc! ---->");
    //this fires ok

});
```

So, from my SAVE_MOC macro i just get a simple error:
Main MOC Error (null)

Let me know if I can provide more info. I'm very new to multi-threading and trying to get a better handle on this approach.

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: You log the wrong error, the parameter should be `e`, not `error`. Perform block is asynchronous, so can you guarantee execution order? Also confinement is deprecated so you should use perform blocks for everything except main context on the main thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In my data loading class I setup the parent/child mocs here to perform
>   the work on the background thread:
>
> ```
> dispatch_queue_t queue =
> dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
> dispatch_async(queue, ^{
>     NSManagedObjectContext *mainMOC = self.managedObjectContext;
>     NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSConfinementConcurrencyType];
> ```

You should not do that.  Do this instead.

```
NSManagedObjectContext *mainMOC = self.managedObjectContext;
NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
```

Make sure you access the MOC in a `performBlock`.  For example,

```
[moc performBlock:^{
    // Anything at all involving this MOC or any of its objects
}];
```

> When the json data has completed I attempt to peform a save operation
>   with the following macro:

Consider saving with something like this.  Your completion block will be called when the save has finished.

```
- (void)saveMOC:(NSManagedObjectContext*)moc
     completion:(void(^)(NSError *error))completion {
    [moc performBlock:^{
        NSError *error = nil;
        if ([moc save:&error]) {
            if (moc.parentContext) {
                return [self saveMOC:moc.parentContext completion:completion];
            }
        }
        if (completion) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                completion(error);
            });
        }
    }];
}

[self saveMOC:moc completion:^(NSError *error) {
    // Completion handler is called from main-thread, after save has finished
    if (error) {
        // Handle error
    } else {
    }
}];
```

**EDIT**

> This code will crash if moc.parentContext is main concurrency type. –
>   Mundi

There is no inherent reason that the code I posted should cause a crash with a parent MOC of `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType`.  It has supported being a parent context ever since parent/child was added to Core Data.

Maybe I was missing a typo, so I copy/paste `saveMOC:completion:` straight from this answer, and wrote the following test helper.

```
- (void)testWithChildConcurrencyType:(NSManagedObjectContextConcurrencyType)childConcurrencyType
               parentConcurrencyType:(NSManagedObjectContextConcurrencyType)parentConcurrencyType {
    NSAttributeDescription *attr = [[NSAttributeDescription alloc] init];
    attr.name = @"attribute";
    attr.attributeType = NSStringAttributeType;
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [[NSEntityDescription alloc] init];
    entity.name = @"Entity";
    entity.properties = @[attr];
    NSManagedObjectModel *model = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] init];
    model.entities = @[entity];

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *psc = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:model];
    [psc addPersistentStoreWithType:NSInMemoryStoreType configuration:nil URL:nil options:nil error:NULL];
    NSManagedObjectContext *parent = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:parentConcurrencyType];
    parent.persistentStoreCoordinator = psc;

    NSManagedObjectContext *child = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:childConcurrencyType];
    child.parentContext = parent;

    NSManagedObject *obj = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Entity" inManagedObjectContext:child];
    [obj setValue:@"value" forKey:@"attribute"];

    XCTestExpectation *expectation = [self expectationWithDescription:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"save from %@ to %@ finished", concurrencyTypeString(childConcurrencyType), concurrencyTypeString(parentConcurrencyType)]];
    [self saveMOC:child completion:^(NSError *error) {
        // Verify data saved all the way to the PSC
        NSManagedObjectContext *localMoc = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
        localMoc.persistentStoreCoordinator = psc;
        NSFetchRequest *fr = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Entity"];
        XCTAssertEqualObjects(@"value", [[[localMoc executeFetchRequest:fr error:NULL] firstObject] valueForKey:@"attribute"]);
        [expectation fulfill];
    }];
    [self waitForExpectationsWithTimeout:10 handler:nil];
}
```

And then, I wrote a test for each possible parent/child relationship.

```
- (void)testThatDoingRecursiveSaveFromPrivateToPrivateWorks {
    [self testWithChildConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType
                 parentConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
}
- (void)testThatDoingRecursiveSaveFromPrivateToMainWorks {
    [self testWithChildConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType
                 parentConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
}
- (void)testThatDoingRecursiveSaveFromMainToPrivateWorks {
    [self testWithChildConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType
                 parentConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
}
- (void)testThatDoingRecursiveSaveFromMainToMainWorks {
    [self testWithChildConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType
                 parentConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
}
```

So, what am I missing?

As I write this, I am reminded of a 360iDev presentation where the presenter said that you can't call `performBlock` on a `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` context.  At the time, I thought he just misspoke, meaning confinement, but maybe there is some confusion in the community about this.

You can't call `performBlock` on a `NSConfinementConcurrencyType` MOC, but `performBlock` is fully supported for `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType`.

Comment: so, i should not be using "dispatch_async" where all the work on the moc is happening....and i should be using NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType instead of the confinement type. thanks for the feedback. i'm definitely up for trying a new approach.

Comment: `dispatch_async` is to be used for other stuff.  Never use confinement-concurrency.  Always use `performBlock` for any core data access.

Comment: This code will crash if `moc.parentContext` is main concurrency type.

Comment: @Mundi - Why do you say that?  I looked at it again, and maybe I'm missing a typo, but I see no obvious reason it should crash.

Comment: Hi, yes, I think it was a typo. Thanks for your copious response :-).

Comment: At least it means someone is reading and keeping me honest.  I like that.

Comment: Ok, I have the perform block structure in place and it is successfully saving. The mainMOC is NSMainQueueConcurrencyType and the child moc is NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType. It isn't crashing but now my tableview isn't populating with the data. Pretty odd.

Comment: Well, we seem to have that problem licked.  It's not considered good form to pile onto one question with others, so you should probably post a new question with your new issue.  When you post the new question, make sure you include your core data stack setup, how you are saving, and how your table view is accessing the data... if it's using a fetched-results-controller, include how that is being setup.

Comment: i was thinking along these lines. new post coming up soon. thanks.

Comment: new post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33620220/core-data-child-context-failing-to-update-main-context

Comment: @flinth Yes.  Do you see something to indicate otherwise?

Comment: @JodyHagins Not really, I'm just confused with saving parent context on the thread where child context is created, which is different thread for parent context. It pushes me to doubt. The docs contains only a few words about it... Thanks for response Jody, I appreciate that.

Comment: The save of the parent is a recursive call, which passes the parent MOC as the context.  So, when the parent saves, it is saving via the parent MOC.